# How do I create a snap for a MonoGame application?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, crossplatform

I've been going through the snapcraft documentation and examples and I'm still really confused about how to go about creating my snapcraft.yaml file.

Basically I have a folder with my game in it.  The folder contains all the files that are needed to run it.

I just want it to copy the files onto the end user's computer and have the shell script that launches the game targeted.

Here is my yaml file:
https://gist.github.com/c349bc23febbe73a6976b83b7757f887

Here are the contents of my directory:
https://github.com/SoundGoddess/OpenSolitaire/releases/download/0.9.2/OpenSolitaire.Classic.0.9.2.Linux.tgz

When I execute "snapcraft snap" I get the following error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

It looks like the parts folder gets generated ok, but then it fails on the build:

```
kati@linux:~/Development/OpenSolitaire.Classic$ snapcraft snap
Skipping pull opensolitaire-classic (already ran)
Preparing to build opensolitaire-classic 
Building opensolitaire-classic 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: looks like all I was missing was a '.' https://gist.github.com/02f1566736b10e3796d148eb4084bb15

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper format:

https://gist.github.com/02f1566736b10e3796d148eb4084bb15

I was missing a '.', thanks to @didrocks in #snappy on freenode for clarifying what I needed to do.

Since the bug was unclear, I posted a bug report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapcraft/+bug/1587455